# How can I get my coloured Bootstrap popover to render properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap popover in my application but there is a white line running through the middle which I can't get rid of. It looks like this:

[image: Bootsrap popover]

Here is how I have the popover defined:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="" value="@product.Quantity" 
data-toggle="popover" title="Contact us" data-placement="top" 
class="input-qty form-control text-center" style="display: block;">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            'placement': 'top',
            html: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.popover {
    background: #ff0000;
}

.popover-title {
    background: #ff0000;
}

.popover.top .arrow:after {
  border-top-color: #ff0000;
}
```

**TypeScript:**

```
(<any>$(e.currentTarget).parents('tr').find('.input-qty')).popover('show');
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried different combinations for the css (which has no effect), like this:

```
.popover .popover-title {
    background: ff0000;
}

.popover.top .arrow:after {
  border-top-color: #ff0000;
}
```

I don't really know what else to try - has anyone else come across anything like this?

Comment: .popover-title {background: #ff0000;border-bottom:0;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal line is the `bottom-border` from the `.popover-title`

See if this works for you:

```
.popover-title {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the line to be a specific color:

```
.popover-title {
    border-bottom-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made border bottom color to `red` if you don't want border you can remove it.
Try this

```
.popover-title {

  border-bottom: 1px solid red; // added this

}
```

If you don't want border then try this

```
.popover-title {

      border-bottom: 0; // added this

    }
```